# Symbol table implementation using hash table in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to implement a simple symbol table that stores the strings in a hash table according to their hash values. The hash table in my program is an array of pointers to linked lists. we have 6 linked lists corresponding to each hash value.

The problem is that though the program runs, it replaces the old strings with the new string in each iteration.

my code is..

```
struct node{
    char *string;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *hashtable[6];

int calchash(char *arr);
main()
    {
    char *line, a='n';
    int val, i;
            do{
            printf("Enter string:\n");
            scanf("%s", line);
            struct node *current;
            struct node *q= (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            q->string = line;
            q->next = NULL;
            val= calchash(line);
            if(hashtable[val] == NULL)
                    {
                    hashtable[val] = q;
                    current =q;}
            else{
                    current->next = q;
                    current = q;
                    }
            printf("Node created\n");
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
            { printf("Hash value %d :\n", i);
            if(hashtable[i]==NULL)
                    {printf("No STRINGS!\n\n");}
            else
                    {struct node *t = hashtable[i];
                    while(t != NULL)
                            {printf("%s \n", t->string);
                            t = t->next;}
                    printf("\n\n");
                   }
            }

    printf("CONTINUE(y/n):\n");
    scanf(" %c", &a);
    }while(a!='n');
    }

int calchash(char *arr)
    {int i=0, ascii;
    int sum=0;
    while(arr[i] != '\0')
            {ascii = arr[i];
            if(ascii>=48 && ascii<=57)
                    {
                    sum+= 2*ascii;}
            else
                    {sum=sum+ ascii;}
            i++;
            }
    return ((sum*17+5)%6);
    }
```

And the output is:
Enter string:
az9

Node created

Hash value 0 :
No STRINGS!

Hash value 1 :
No STRINGS!

Hash value 2 :
az9

Hash value 3 :
No STRINGS!

Hash value 4 :
No STRINGS!

Hash value 5 :
No STRINGS!

CONTINUE(y/n):
y

Enter string:
Az9

Node created

Hash value 0 :
No STRINGS!

Hash value 1 :
No STRINGS!

Hash value 2 :
Az9

Hash value 3 :
No STRINGS!

Hash value 4 :
Az9

Hash value 5 :
No STRINGS!

CONTINUE(y/n):
n

Can someone please tell me what changes are needed so as to retain the previous az9 string under hash value 2???

Comment: Please format properly.

Comment: You know that superfluous Casts are bad form and tend to muzzle the compiler? Never cast the return value of `malloc()`. How about trying to compile with all warnings enabled, and actually fixing the warnings properly?

Comment: What platform is this running on?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(hashtable[val] == NULL) {
    hashtable[val] = q;
    current =q;
} else {
    current->next = q;
    current = q;
}
```

should be replaced with:

```
q->next = hashtable[val];
hashtable[val] = q;
// no need for current
```

Also, writing through any uninitialised pointer is UB, please allocate sufficient space first. Anything might happen...

Answer (score 1):

How does this not crash immediately?  Neither `line` nor `hashtable` are initialized.

You will need to make a copy of the string to go into each hash node, probably with `strdup`.  Currently, all of the nodes point to the same string buffer as `line`, so when you read a new string into `line`, all of the nodes will see it.  This is why you must duplicate the string for each node.  I wonder where the buffer ended up though, since you never initialized `line`...

Also, what is `current`?  It is local to the loop, and appears unnecessary.  You should just chain new nodes onto the head of the bucket, so you don't need to check if the bucket is empty.

The insert also does not check if the string is already present, so you will insert duplicates.